# The loop keeps overflowing

Tags: java, math

For my school project i am making a program that uses probability to calculate the value of pi, I need the loop in the program to run for at least 20000 times but my program is not going more than 4000.

here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    game();
    System.out.println(pi);
}

public static void game(){
    if(total >= 4000){
    return;
    }
    randomNum = 1.1;
    generatex();
    generatey();
    distance(randomx, randomy);
    game();
    return;
}

private static void distance(double x, double y) {
    double dist = Math.sqrt((x*x)+(y*y));
    if(dist <= 1){
        ++in;
    }
        ++total;
    if(total != 0){
    pi = 4 * (in/total);
    }
}

public static double generatex(){
    random();
    randomx = randomNum;
    return randomx;
}   

public static double generatey(){
    random();
    randomy = randomNum;
    return randomy;
}

public static double random() {
    randomNum = rand.nextDouble();
    if(randomNum <= 1){
        return randomNum;
    }
    random();
    return 0d;
}
```

}

Comment: Why not use a loop?

Comment: btw there's no need to compute the sqrt (which is expensive): the inequality is equivalent without it.

Comment: You don't have a loop in your program, do you mean the recursion? 
What do you mean with "not going"? Stackoverflow?

Comment: `if(total >= 4000)` should be `if(total >= 20000)`

Comment: Calculate pi by throwing frozen hot dogs: http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Pi-by-Throwing-Frozen-Hot-Dogs

Answer (score 3):

Change the line

```
    if(total >= 4000){
```

to

```
    if(total >= 20000){
```